# A simple function that removes empty or tags containing just '&nbsp;'

Tags: javascript, strings, html, ecmascript-6

I've written a function that should get rid of empty p, span, etc tags and those with just ' ' and am looking for ways to improve it. My original solution was very 'wet', but I've managed to come up with a drier solution.

The Original HTML:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='test'>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p><span>text</span></p>
    <p><span></span></p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p><strong>text</strong></p>
    <p></p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p><span><strong>&nbsp;</strong></span></p>
    <p><span><strong>text</strong></span></p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p><span>text</span></p>
    <p></p>
    <p><span></span></p>
    <p><span>&nbsp;</span></p>
    <p><span><strong></strong></span></p>
    <p>text</p>
</div>
```

My Original Solution:

```
/*
    How to make this drier?
    ORIGINAL UNCLEAN SOLUTION
*/
    var ps = document.getElementsByTagName('p'),
    spans = document.getElementsByTagName('span'),
    strongs = document.getElementsByTagName('strong');

    for (let el of ps) {
        if (el.innerHTML == '&nbsp;') { // can't also include if '' at this stage
            el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
        }
    }
    for (let el of spans) {
        if (el.innerHTML == '&nbsp;' || el.innerHTML == '') {
            el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
        }
    }
    for (let el of strongs) {
        if (el.innerHTML == '&nbsp;' || el.innerHTML == '') {
            el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
        }
    }
    for (let el of ps) {
        if (el.innerHTML == '') {
            el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
        }
    }
```

My 'drier' solution:

```
/*
    MY CLEANER SOLUTION
*/
    var ps = document.getElementsByTagName('p'),
    spans = document.getElementsByTagName('span'),
    strongs = document.getElementsByTagName('strong');

    for (let el of ps) {
        cleaner(el);
    }
    for (let el of spans) {
        cleaner(el);
    }
    for (let el of strongs) {
        cleaner(el);
    }

    function cleaner(el) {
        if (el.innerHTML == '&nbsp;' || el.innerHTML == '') {
            el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
        }
    }
```

Would someone mind quickly running over both solutions and verifying that my 2nd solution is best? Also, I wonder whether that could be improved, or whether anyone has any better ideas for a solution? Thanks for the help here - for brevity, I'm looking at writing concise but also clear code.

Comment: Does the code at the question produce the expected result? Should `<p></p>` be a child element of `#test` following execution of the code? Can you include the expected resulting HTML at the question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## There is a bug

You need to run the script several times to remove all empty elements.

### Two points

1. You say remove empty tags that contain `""` or a single space `"&nbsp;"`. Does that include `" "` or `"  "` two or more spaces. What about other white space characters?
2. Your element removal is order dependent because you use `getElementsByTagName` which returns a live list.

   Consider the html `<p><span></span></p>`  You first check all the `p` tags which fail the empty test, then you test the `span` tags which passes and you get `<p></p>` which is, by your definition, empty and should have been removed.

   On the other hand the html `<span><p></p></span>` will first remove the `p` then remove the `span`.

   The removal process is order dependent. Not what your question indicates.

### Changes

For the first point you could use `element.textContent` to check for empty elements. It will ignore the HTML and convert the `&nbsp;` to a space for you. You could even use `element.textContent.trim()` and thus get all blank elements (like the pseudo-class `:blank` (Which has very limited support FF only))

This also covers the second point.

#### Example Mark and remove

To reduce the DOM calls you can mark and remove deleting the marked elements only.

```
const isNotMarked = el => {
    while (el && el.parentNode && !el.parentNode.marked) {
       el = el.parentNode;
       if (el.marked) { return false }
    }
    return true;
}
[...document.querySelectorAll("span, p, strong")]
    .filter(el => el.textContent.trim() === "" && isNotMarked(el) ? el.marked = true : false)
    .forEach(el => el.parentNode.removeChild(el));
```

#### Example simple brute force

Mark and remove saves you attempting to delete already deleted elements but you may not care, as the shorter form, is a two liner, and thus could be argued to be the better solution.

```
document.querySelectorAll("span, p, strong")
    .forEach(el => el.textContent.trim() === "" && el.parentNode.removeChild(el))
```

The following snippet shows the HTML after using your function and then the two example functions

```js
   /*================================================================================= 
OP ver modified for example
 =================================================================================*/

var ps = cleaned.getElementsByTagName('p'),
    spans = cleaned.getElementsByTagName('span'),
    strongs = cleaned.getElementsByTagName('strong');

    for (let el of ps) { cleaner(el); }
    for (let el of spans) {  cleaner(el); }
    for (let el of strongs) { cleaner(el);  }

    function cleaner(el) {
        if (el.innerHTML == '&nbsp;' || el.innerHTML == '') {
            el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
        }
    }
    content.textContent = cleaned.innerHTML;




/*================================================================================= 
 Mark and remove
 =================================================================================*/
const isNotMarked = el => {
    while (el && el.parentNode && !el.parentNode.marked) {
       el = el.parentNode;
       if (el.marked) { return false }
    }
    return true;
}
[...cleanerClean.querySelectorAll("span, p, strong")]
    .filter(el =>  el.textContent.trim() === "" && isNotMarked(el) ? el.marked = true : false)
    .forEach(el => el.parentNode.removeChild(el));

contentA.textContent = cleanerClean.innerHTML;



/*================================================================================= 
 Brute force remove
 =================================================================================*/
simplerClean.querySelectorAll("span, p, strong")
    .forEach(el => el.textContent.trim() === "" && el.parentNode.removeChild(el))

contentB.textContent = simplerClean.innerHTML;
```

```css
#content {
   display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="cleaned" style="display:none;">
  <p>text</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p><span>text</span></p>
  <p><span></span></p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p><strong>text</strong></p>
  <p></p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p><span><strong>&nbsp;</strong></span></p>
  <p><span><strong>text</strong></span></p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p><span>text</span></p>
  <p></p>
  <p><span></span></p>
  <p><span>&nbsp;</span></p>
  <p><span><strong></strong></span></p>
  <p>text</p>
</div>  
<fieldset>
<legend>Original OPs script & Resulting HTML</legend>
<code id = "content"></code>
</fieldset>


<div id="cleanerClean"  style="display:none;">
  <p>text</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p><span>text</span></p>
  <p><span></span></p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p><strong>text</strong></p>
  <p></p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p><span><strong>&nbsp;</strong></span></p>
  <p><span><strong>text</strong></span></p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p><span>text</span></p>
  <p></p>
  <p><span></span></p>
  <p><span>&nbsp;</span></p>
  <p><span><strong></strong></span></p>
  <p>text</p>
</div>  

<fieldset>
<legend>Mark and remove</legend>
<code id = "contentA"></code>
</fieldset>

<div id="simplerClean"  style="display:none;">
  <p>text</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p><span>text</span></p>
  <p><span></span></p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p><strong>text</strong></p>
  <p></p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p><span><strong>&nbsp;</strong></span></p>
  <p><span><strong>text</strong></span></p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p><span>text</span></p>
  <p></p>
  <p><span></span></p>
  <p><span>&nbsp;</span></p>
  <p><span><strong></strong></span></p>
  <p>text</p>
</div>  

<fieldset>
<legend>Brute force remove</legend>
<code id = "contentB"></code>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Maybe you should use el.innerHTML.trim() instead. In my case, <p><img ..></p> was removed aswell.

Comment: +1'd the answer, though for the brute force I would have split the `forEach` into a `filter` and a `forEach`, it would be semantically correct, and slower.

Comment: @konijn Thanks. Note that `querySelectorAll` returns an array like object and thus would require at least a spread operator. to work. eg `[...document.querySelectorAll("span, p, strong")].filter(`

Answer (score 4):

I support the main aspect of [Carra's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/210884/120114) (i.e. using `querySelectorAll()`). In addition, a functional approach can be used, since the function `cleaner` is applied to each element. For that, utilize [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

```
elements.forEach(cleaner);
```

That way, there is no need to set up an iterator variable (e.g. `el` in the `for...of`) loop just to pass it to the function. The function will receive the element as the first parameter each time it is called - once for each element in the collection.

Additionally, since [ecmascript-6](/questions/tagged/ecmascript-6) features like `for...of` and `let` are used, others like [`const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) can be used (e.g. for any variable that doesn't need to be re-assigned). One could also use [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) if desired.

And it would be a good habit to use the [strict equality comparison](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness) (i.e. `===`) when comparing the innerHTML properties with the strings.

```js
function cleaner(el) {
  if (el.innerHTML === '&nbsp;' || el.innerHTML === '') {
    el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
  }
}

const elements = document.querySelectorAll('p, span, strong');
elements.forEach(cleaner);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='test'>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p><span>text</span></p>
  <p><span></span></p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p><strong>text</strong></p>
  <p></p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p><span><strong>&nbsp;</strong></span></p>
  <p><span><strong>text</strong></span></p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p><span>text</span></p>
  <p></p>
  <p><span></span></p>
  <p><span>&nbsp;</span></p>
  <p><span><strong></strong></span></p>
  <p>text</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [querySelectorAll](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselectorall.asp) to simplify your code further:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('p, span, strong'),

for (let el of elements) {
    cleaner(el);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Beside suggested improvements:

1. If `<p>    </p>` is an empty element to you, then change your `cleaner()`:

   ```
   function cleaner(el) {
     if (el.innerHTML.match(/^\s+$/) !== null) {
       el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
     }
   }
   ```
2. You might need to consider going recursive towards elements that have been emptied because of your cleaning procedure.
3. **[Edit]** I'm used to verbal function names (a best practice to follow), so I would suggest using `clean` or `remove` instead of `cleaner`.